# Output multiple custom log Apache2

Tags: linux, logging, apache2

is it possible to output access log and error log to multiple folder
with different format (Custom log) ?

i wish to have a format for me and one for my clients.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/logs.html

Comment: Depends: multiple vhosts = possible multiple logs, one vhost/server = one log (but multiple files for the same log are possible)

Comment: i would like, multiple vhost with multiple logs, how can i acheve that ? simply iwth stacking logs param ?

Comment: For each vhost you can only have one custom log directive (= one log), but this log can be written into multiple files. What exactly do you want?